# Adding 2 pictures to a video with avconv

Tags: libav, avconv

Here is the command that I am using to add a logo to a stream

```
avconv -f alsa -i pulse -f x11grab -s hd720 -i :1.0+nomouse -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 -threads auto -f flv rtmp://server
```

How can I add a second picture to the stream? Is there a way to do this without using -filter_complex as it's not available?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just add another set of `movie` and `overlay` filters. Something like (split over multiple lines for clarity)

```
-vf "
movie=logo1.png [watermark1];
movie=logo2.png [watermark2];
[in][watermark1] overlay=x1:y1 [watermarked1];
[watermarked1][watermark2]overlay=x2:y2[out]
"
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying something similar like you showed me but never got the correct way.